# Running Fitnesse Tests from Command Line

Tags: fitnesse

When running the Fitnesse tests via command Line I am getting a ClassNotFound Exception

caused by Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:fitnesse.runner.testRunner

could not find the main class:fitnesse.runner.TestRunner.Program will exit

Kindly help

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

TestRunner is no longer supported.  Use http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.CommandLineRestCommands

Update: link has changed - http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.ControllingFitNesseFromTheCommandLine

Update: link has changed again - http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ControllingFitNesseFromTheCommandLine

Excerpt from Fitnesse docs:

> You can run any REST command (See Restful Services) from the command
>   line by using the -c command line option as follows:
>
> java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -c
>
> This starts up fitnesse, runs the command, emits the output to
>   standard out, and then exits.
>
> Most often you will use this to run tests and/or suites from the
>   command line as follows:
>
> java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -c "MyTestPage?test&format=text"

Comment: Does this also apply to the DotNetTestRunner or is this only for java projects.

Comment: The .NET TestRunner is also deprecated.

Comment: I followed the CommandLineRestCommands guide but, as of fitnesse Build #278 (Feb 16, 2013), invoking
`java -jar fitnesse.jar -c 'PageName?test'`

throws a 

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context`. Actually the same happens when omitting `-c` option. Isn't this wrong?!

Comment: @Mike Stockdale, so what should we use instead to run tests from the command line?

Comment: see http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.ControllingFitNesseFromTheCommandLine

Comment: http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ControllingFitNesseFromTheCommandLine